# CVS cannot lock file?

Tags: cvs

I will make this simple :

1. Added a file to the server
2. I Commit this file to the server

   Result: cvs server:cannot lock 'D:/cvsnt_repos/[...],v'.

First, what does "cannot lock" mean?
Second, why does it do that with this particular file (it is a .CSS)?

Every post that I have read about this was never answered. With your help, maybe we can make this question a reference on the net and help the community !

Comment: hum, there is a problem with locking a revision in the RCS file. Can you show the output of "cvs log -h" on that file?

Comment: here it is: RCS file: /cvsnt_repos/[...],v
Working file: layout_formulaire.css
head:
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 0

Comment: I have no idea why it happens but it happens frequently. I haven't found any other solution but to go to CVS repository and delete the file in question. Yes, history is lost, but at least I can commit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your CVS repository may already contain a file with the same name but different uppercase/lowercase letters. So it rejects the new commit with reason: `cvs server: cannot lock [filename]`.

Windows is a case insensitive platform, but CVS (server on Unix) isn't and this causes lots of issues with case sensitivity.
Example: trying to commit "some**f**ile.css" when "some**F**ile.css" is already in the CVS repository (but in another CVS branch, so you don't see it in your current WinCVS listing).

To confirm, either browse all your CVS branches in WinCVS or else, run a CVS log command from the shell. From the folder where the CSS file is being added, type:

```
cvs log * > log.txt
```

(The output can be quite large, so it's better redirected to file)

Open log.txt in your preferred editor, and search (case insensitive!) for the offending file name. If you find a file name with different case, bingo.

To resolve this either you have to manually change the case in the CVS server, or else keep the original name (someFile.css) in your new commit.

note: deleting the file from all your CVS branches does not help, as CVS keeps anyway track of deleted files.

See also:

- https://groups.google.com/g/gnu.cvs.bug/c/gw0fOhl6Wfg

Quoting:

> You have similarly named but differently cased files in your repository
> and CVS doesn't know which one to pick. This is due to a fix I recently
> checked in for a problem where a recase from a case-insensitive system
> such as Windows would cause an assertion failure and archive corruption.
> Now when a CVS server finds two files that would be identical for the
> case-insensitive system, it refuses to go any further.
>
> The immediate work-around is to rename or remove one of the archive files.

- http://www.cvsnt.org/pipermail/cvsnt/2003-June/007047.html

Quoting:

> CVSNT is Windows based. Windows does *not* recognize a difference in case of a file, so I think you are out of luck here if you want to use C style case sensitivity in file names...
> If you really want this to be changed (for cosmetic reasons) then I suggest the following (if you have access to the repository directly):
>
> 1. Stop the CVS service
> 2. Go and find the repository files you want to change (here foo.txt,v)
> 3. Change the name of the file (here to Foo.txt,v)
> 4. Start the CVS service
> 5. Check out the module again (no use doing an update because Windows does not see the difference).